# Retrieve primary key from entity class from sessionfactory in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory

I am creating one SessionFactory using hibernate and I need the primary key of all the tables associated with the entity classes generated from the SessionFactory. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have created SessionFactory and from the gathered the ClassMetaData. But unable to retrieve the primary key from the ClassMetaData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which Hibernate version you have. This works for version 4.2.x:

```
Configuration con = // get the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
for(Iterator<PersistentClass> itpc = con.getClassMappings();itpc.hasNext();)
{
    PersistentClass pc = itpc.next();
    System.out.println(pc.getEntityName() + ", " + pc.getNodeName());
    System.out.println("Identifier(s):");
    Property idpy = pc.getIdentifierProperty();
    for(Iterator<?> itpy = idpy.getColumnIterator();itpy.hasNext();)
    {
        Object o = itpy.next();
        if(o instanceof Column)
        {
            Column c = (Column)o;
            System.out.println(c.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes ... that helps actually ... thanks a lot @user7399085